# Как перевести счетчик обратного отсчета на русский?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Запускаю счетчик через `moment-countdown`. Приходит ответ: `1 day, 5 hours and 59 minutes`.
Мне нужен ответ в формате: `1д 5ч 59м`.
Не могу разобраться, язык написал:

```js
moment.locale('ru');
let standart = moment().tz("Europe/Moscow").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
let nowDay = moment(standart, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var eventDay = moment('2023-05-10 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
let timers = moment(nowDay, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').countdown(eventDay, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm").toString();
console.log(timers);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51663268/21493925 не помогает?